# Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

Tags: android, flutter, webapi

I want integrate Flutter with an ASP.NET API. the problem is when I create search using bloc, I got this exception catch but I cannot find where the error is. This is my code:

```
  Future<void> fetchUsers()async {

    final Dio _dio = Dio();
     const String _url = 'https://juslinkhere.com/c&s/here/all';
      Response response = await _dio.get(_url, options: Options(headers:{"key: token"},));
    try {

      var body = jsonDecode(response.data);
      final Iterable list = body["result"];
      totalUsers = list.map((model)=>listmodel.fromJson(model)).toList();

      userBloc.userController.sink.add(totalUsers);

    }
    catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
    }
    
  }
```

I want to create searching data in bloc, this is another exception from dio in vscode

```
void next(DioException err) { _completer.completeError(
```

This is my widget:

```
Widget UsersWidget(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: userBloc.userController.stream,
      builder: (BuildContext buildContext, AsyncSnapshot <List<listmodel>> snapshot) {
        if(snapshot == null){
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      
      return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
      ? const Center( 
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
      : ListView.builder( 
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title:  Text('${snapshot.data![index].rows![index].id}'),
            subtitle:  Text('${snapshot.data![index].rows![index].dateoflastinsp}'),
            leading: const Icon(Icons.edit_road),
            trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
            onTap:() {
              Navigator.push(
                context, 
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> DetailsScreen(index))
                );
            },
          ),
        );
        }
      );
      }
      );
  
  }
```

and this is my model generated from JSON to dart converter github

```
class listmodel {
  String? drainageid;
  int? datacount;
  int? resultcount;
  String? page;
  List<Rows>? rows;
  String? error;

  listmodel(
      {this.drainageid,
      this.datacount,
      this.resultcount,
      this.page,
      this.rows});

  listmodel.withError(String errorMessage) {
    error = errorMessage;
  }

  listmodel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    drainageid = json['drainageid'];
    datacount = json['datacount'];
    resultcount = json['resultcount'];
    page = json['page'];
    if (json['rows'] != null) {
      rows = <Rows>[];
      json['rows'].forEach((v) {
        rows!.add(Rows.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['drainageid'] = drainageid;
    data['datacount'] = datacount;
    data['resultcount'] = resultcount;
    data['page'] = page;
    if (rows != null) {
      data['rows'] = rows!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Rows {
  String? id;
  String? dateoflastinsp;
  String? dateofinsp;
  String? inspby;

  Rows({this.id, this.dateoflastinsp, this.dateofinsp, this.inspby});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    dateoflastinsp = json['dateoflastinsp'];
    dateofinsp = json['dateofinsp'];
    inspby = json['inspby'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['dateoflastinsp'] = dateoflastinsp;
    data['dateofinsp'] = dateofinsp;
    data['inspby'] = inspby;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I want to display the `id` and `dateoflastinp` in card listview but somehow it come out as object instead of String.

Comment: Can you give the response that you are fetching.

Comment: Some field in your response is a map and not a string. That's what the error says. The error lies probably in your listmodel. If you give us an example response and your listmodel we can help you better

Comment: If you are using Dio, you don't need to use jsonDecode as Dio handles that automatically for you, so perhaps the jsonDecode method is still decoding the already decoded response.

Comment: @AlwayssBijoy i have update the question and i put model and a widget

Comment: @Ivo i have update the question and i put model and a widget

Comment: My guess is that the `page` field is actually a map and not a string. But can't tell for sure without seeing the response